# Using itms-services links in an app on the App Store

Tags: ios, iphone, adhoc, ad-hoc-distribution

I've been working on a simplified, web-based ad-hoc build management service for a while now, and I'm going over the possibilities to my make clients life easier.

While one possibility is to simply create a web app optimized for iOS, I'd rather have a native app instead.

Now, I haven't found any clear advice on whether or not Apple is okay with apps using itms-services links, which would then install 3rd party non-App Store apps, as long as they were signed ad-hoc/Enterprise builds.

In my case, the apps in question would be tied to a specific user/group, and would be behind a login/signup.

Currently all I'm doing is:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:_appInstallUrl];
```

Also, if Apple would be okay with an app like this on the App Store, how would they feel about forcefully suspending apps?

I'm currently doing this right after installing the app:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] performSelector:@selector(suspend)];
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be a violation to the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

- 2.8 Apps that install or launch other executable code will be rejected
- 2.25 Apps that display Apps other than your own for purchase or promotion in a manner similar to or confusing with the App Store will be rejected

But you'll only know if you directly ask Apple, or simply submit it and it goes through.

Comment: Thanks! Although the apps wouldn't be available for purchase, and wouldn't be promotional (the user would have to apply for access to a single app/build, for testing purposes), I'll try and ask Apple directly, then post back here. I'm not holding my breath, just wondering what their stance is after they've done the same thing with Testflight. :)

Comment: The thing is, TestFlight never had an app before they were bought. And you can probably imagine that there are other rules for Apple themselves. Good luck!

Comment: I know, and I don't mind going with a web app only. A native solution would just be so much nicer, but I guess we'll know soon enough if Apple OK's the idea.

Answer (score 1):

*Posting this as an answer, since it's the official response from Apple.*

I first contacted Apple's technical support regarding this, but they couldn't help and instead wanted me to contact the App Store Review Team, remembering to mention that a technician had told me to contact them.

They finally responded with the following:

*Thank you for contacting the App Store Review Team.*

*Please know we are not able to pre-approve proposed application ideas or concepts for developers without reviewing the app itself.*

*Each application is unique and we would need to look at all its features, and complexity to be able to give you an answer.*

*Therefore, we recommend that you submit your application for review. We will then contact you if we have any questions.*

*However, for your questions we do recommend that you review the Functionality and Privacy sections within our iOS guidelines:*

*2.22: Apps that arbitrarily restrict which users may use the App, such as by location or carrier, may be rejected*

*17.2: Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected*

While this technically doesn't answer my question (at all), it would seem like the idea/app could still go through, depending on the reviewer. At least they don't seem to be against the idea.