# 2.5.2 - Performance - Software Requirements

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, app-store-connect

Anyone come across this case, What is the root cause for this ?

From Apple

**Guideline 2.5.2 - Performance - Software Requirements**

Also, during review, your app installed or launched executable code, which is not permitted on the App Store. Specifically, your app uses the itms-services URL scheme to install an app.

**Important Information**

As a result of violating this guideline, your app’s review has been delayed. Future submissions of this app, and other apps associated with your Apple Developer account, will also experience a delayed review. Deliberate disregard of the App Store Review Guidelines and attempts to deceive users or undermine the review process are unacceptable and is a direct violation Section 3.2(f) of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement. Continuing to violate the Terms & Conditions of the Apple Developer Program will result in the termination of your account, as well as any related or linked accounts, and the removal of all your associated apps from the App Store.

We want to provide a safe experience for users to get apps and a fair environment for for all developers to be successful. If you believe we have misunderstood or misinterpreted the intent of your app, you may submit an appeal for consideration or provide additional clarification by responding directly to this message in Resolution Center in iTunes Connect.

**Guideline 4.0 - Design**

Furthermore, your app includes an update button or alerts the user to update the app. To avoid user confusion, app version updates must utilize the iOS built-in update mechanism.

**Next Steps**

To resolve this issue, please remove the update feature from your app. To distribute a new version of your app, upload the new app binary version into the same iTunes Connect record you created for the app's previous version. Updated versions keep the same Apple ID, iTunes Connect ID (SKU), and bundle ID as the original version, and are available free to customers who purchased a previous version.

**List of iOS pods used by us**

pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.8'

```
pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
pod 'ObjectMapper', '~> 2.2'
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'CWStatusBarNotification', '~> 2.3.5'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
pod 'GeoFire', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc.git'
```

Comment: Apple itself clearly stated What is this & how to resolve this both issues.What you expect more?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App Store Rejection: Performance: App Completeness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356595/app-store-rejection-performance-app-completeness)

Comment: The root cause of what?  You are not really explaining anything except that you show direct guideline violation statement from Apple.  If I read it, It seems that you are trying to install files outside of the iTunes Connect system, which seems stupid to me if that's the case.

Comment: I looked for keyword itms-services in my entire source code, nowhere it was used.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the whole issue is related to the fact that you are trying to inform your users wheh newer version of the application is in the AppStore but Apple do not tolerate such thing.

Comment: But, there is no code logic to prompt user to force update newer version. Is there any other possible?

Comment: I am also facing same issue, Apple rejected app with description that, your app uses the itms-services URL scheme to install an app. Do you found any solution to this, because I am not using any itms url schemes and not showing any update alert. Same app was approved 2 months ago. Please share any one have the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this
[Using itms-services links in an app on the App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31217194/using-itms-services-links-in-an-app-on-the-app-store?rq=1)
and issue is not with your update through alert, that will be fine when you submit another binary (without alert), main issue is with "itms-services URL scheme to install an app" you may be installing another application without notifying user or you may be opening/installing an application without showing a proper message to user.

Answer (score 0):

pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'

are deprecated.
You should use latest Facebook SDK instead.
I had the same problem with apple review